# Javascript equivalent to RNGCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, javascript

I am using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` to generate some simple keys for something in C#, but I have a situation where I need to generate these on the client side using Javascript.

I can just call to the server and get it, but I was wanting to avoid yet another server request on an already server heavy load. The code I am using is as follows; I cannot find the equivalent to `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` in Javascript, though, or anything similar to it.

I can translate pretty much everything here, except for that one class... It is really starting to bother me...

```
/// <summary>
/// Generate a key of a given length with specific characters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="length">
/// The length of the key to generate.
/// </param>
/// <param name="allowedChars">
/// The characters allowed in the key.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// A generated key.
/// </returns>
public static string Create(int length, string allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") {
    if (length < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", "length cannot be less than zero.");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(allowedChars)) throw new ArgumentException("allowedChars may not be empty.");

    const int byteSize = 0x100;
    var allowedCharSet = new HashSet<char>(allowedChars).ToArray();
    if (byteSize < allowedCharSet.Length) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("allowedChars may contain no more than {0} characters.", byteSize));

    // Guid.NewGuid and System.Random are not particularly random. By using a
    // cryptographically-secure random number generator, the caller is always
    // protected, regardless of use.
    using (var rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider()) {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        var buf = new byte[128];
        while (result.Length < length) {
            rng.GetBytes(buf);
            for (var i = 0; i < buf.Length && result.Length < length; ++i) {
                // Divide the byte into allowedCharSet-sized groups. If the
                // random value falls into the last group and the last group is
                // too small to choose from the entire allowedCharSet, ignore
                // the value in order to avoid biasing the result.
                var outOfRangeStart = byteSize - (byteSize % allowedCharSet.Length);
                if (outOfRangeStart <= buf[i]) continue;
                result.Append(allowedCharSet[buf[i] % allowedCharSet.Length]);
            }
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have more specific questions about that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to go for server sided call, as JavaScript is client-sided language and its not safe for security keys, as it complete algo can be viewed and re-engineering may expose your values.

So one call to server side is not that expensive.

Comment: That's a fair argument. I had not put a lot of stock in the strength, because these are more for identification than actual security. It is just to generate some "indexes" so that different items in a collection can be referenced more easily. I will probably end up with a server side call.